Possible to annotate inline "this" with comment types with Flow?
Getting this error:

Missing an annotation on implicit this parameter of function.

Would be nice to be able to annotate this with comment types. Possible?
https://flow.org/en/docs/types/comments/

You can put any Flow syntax that isn't supposed to be seen in the JS output inside /*:: (two times :) and */.
Including the whole this annotation.

function baz(/*:: this: Foo */){}


Try Flow
